# Field not found: 'Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lucene, umbraco

After moving from `ASP.NET MVC 4.0` to `ASP.NET MVC 4.5` and updating all the installed packages I'm getting an error:

> "Field not found: 'Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29'."

In my `.config` files there are the following rows.

`package.config`:

```
< package id="Lucene.Net" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

`web.config`:

```
< dependentAssembly>
        < assemblyIdentity name="Lucene.Net" publicKeyToken="85089178b9ac3181" culture="neutral" />
        < bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.3.0" newVersion="3.0.3.0" />
      < /dependentAssembly>
```

How do I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you were is ASP .NET MVC 4.0 at that time Package.confg must be showing package.config:

< package id="Lucene.Net" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net40" />

As targetFramewrork tells the version of .NET Framework version this assembly was compiled against so, I would like you to set it to "net40" instead of "net45" and rebuild the solution.

Hope this helps.